# cake php pagination not displaying the array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to retrieve data by using cakephp pagination.Here i am missing an array.When i try to get the data the **NewsFeedCommentLike** is missing from the result set.How can i solve this.I tried different approaches, but nothing is working, really i am struck with this.

Thanks..

Here is my code:

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('NewsFeed.group_id'=>$groupdata['Group']['id'],'NewsFeed.status'=>'A'),
            'joins' => array(
                    array(
                            'alias' => 'newslikes',
                            'table' => 'news_feed_likes',
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array('newslikes.news_feed_id = NewsFeed.id','newslikes.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'),'newslikes.status'=>'1')
                    )
            ),
            'fields' => array('IFNULL(newslikes.user_id,0) AS likestatus','NewsFeed.id','NewsFeed.posted_message','NewsFeed.created','NewsFeed.user_id','NewsFeed.status','NewsFeed.newslike'
                    ,'IFNULL(newslikes.status,0) AS status'),
            'order' => array(
                    'NewsFeed.created' => 'desc'
            )
    );

    $this->set('newsfeed', $this->paginate( $this->NewsFeed ) );
```

Below is my result:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'likestatus' => '0',
        'status' => '0'
    ),
    'NewsFeed' => array(
        'id' => '12',
        'posted_message' => 'Test...',
        'user_id' => '2',
        'status' => 'A',
        'newslike' => '0'
    ),
    'Group' => array(),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '2',
        'username' => 'sssss',
        'Email' => 'test@email.com',
        'facebook_id' => '0',
        'First_Name' => 'Sam',
        'avatar' => null,

    ),
    'NewsFeedComment' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '16',
            'news_feed_id' => '11',
            'comments' => 'test reply',
            'user_id' => '1',
                    'created' => '2013-12-13 13:52:50',
            'replylikecount' => '0'
        )
    ),
    'NewsFeedLike' => array()
),
```

These are my models:

NewsFeed.php

```
<?php
class NewsFeed extends AppModel {

var $name = 'NewsFeed';

var $useTable = 'news_feeds';
var $primaryKey = 'id';


var $hasMany = array(

        'NewsFeedComment' => array(
                'className' => 'NewsFeedComment',

        ),

        'NewsFeedLike' => array(
                'className' => 'NewsFeedLike',

        ),




);

var $belongsTo = array(
        'Group'=> array (
                'className' => 'Group',
                'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        ),

        'User'=> array (
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
);





}
?>
```

NewsFeedComment:

```
<?php
class NewsFeedComment extends AppModel {

var $name = 'NewsFeedComment';
var $useTable = 'news_feed_comments';
var $primaryKey = 'id';

var $hasMany = array(


        'NewsFeedCommentLike' => array(
                'className' => 'NewsFeedCommentLike',

        ),




);


var $belongsTo = array(
        'NewsFeed'=> array (
                'className' => 'NewsFeed',
                'foreignKey' => 'news_feed_id'
        ),

        'User'=> array (
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
);

}
?>
```

NewsFeedLike.php

```
<?php
class NewsFeedLike extends AppModel {

var $name = 'NewsFeedLike';
var $useTable = 'news_feed_likes';
var $primaryKey = 'id';


var $belongsTo = array(
        'NewsFeed'=> array (
                'className' => 'NewsFeed',
                'foreignKey' => 'news_feed_id'
        ),

        'User'=> array (
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
);

}
?>
```

NewsFeedCommentLike.php

```
<?php
class NewsFeedCommentLike extends AppModel {

var $name = 'NewsFeedCommentLike';
var $useTable = 'news_feed_comments_likes';
var $primaryKey = 'id';


var $belongsTo = array(

        'NewsFeed'=> array (
                'className' => 'NewsFeed',
                'foreignKey' => 'news_feed__id',

        ),

        'NewsFeedComment'=> array (
                'className' => 'NewsFeedComment',
                'foreignKey' => 'news_feed_comment_id',

        ),

        'User'=> array (
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
);

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your view? Have you loaded pagination?

Comment: Yes i have loaded the pagination

Comment: please see my edit, i have added the result iam getting after loding the pagination, pls let me know if any other information is required

Answer (score 0):

Start by reducing the conditions to bare minimums. Then add in the conditions, joins, etc. to see where the trouble may start.

Also, it may help to follow convention on your join. Change `newslikes` to `NewsFeedLike`.